# clojure's commute example from the docs produces duplicates

Tags: concurrency, clojure

this setup is **straight** outta the docs here:
https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/commute

I'll just copy the code as is, with my comments:

```
(def counter (ref 0))

(defn alter-inc! [counter]
     (dosync (Thread/sleep 100) (alter counter inc)))

(defn commute-inc! [counter]
  (dosync (Thread/sleep 100) (commute counter inc)))

(defn bombard-counter! [n f counter]
  (apply pcalls (repeat n #(f counter))))

(dosync (ref-set counter 0))
```

Running with the alter produces the randomly ordered list and takes 2000 ms, like in the example:

```
> (time (doall (bombard-counter! 20 alter-inc! counter)))
"Elapsed time: 2078.859995 msecs"
(7 6 1 5 4 2 3 9 12 10 8 14 11 13 15 18 16 17 20 19)
```

But running with commute does something very different from the claim in the official doc - I get duplicates:

```
> (time (doall (bombard-counter! 20 commute-inc! counter)))
"Elapsed time: 309.615195 msecs"
(5 1 1 6 5 4 1 8 8 10 10 12 14 13 15 16 17 18 19 20)
```

And that's definitely not the result promised in the docs! The difference in the running time is as advertised, but what with the duplicates? I'm prone to typos, so I've re-done it from scratch - same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “commute returns the new value of the ref. **However, the last in-transaction value you see from a commute will not always match the end-of-transaction value of a ref, because of reordering**. If another transaction sneaks in and alters a ref that you are trying to commute, the STM will not restart your transaction. Instead, it will simply run your commute function again, out of order. Your transaction will never even see the ref value that your commute function finally ran against."
>
> Since Clojure’s STM can reorder commutes behind your back, you can use
>   them only when you do not care about ordering.”

Excerpt From: Stuart Halloway. “Programming Clojure.”

This is the reason you see out of order update results in your output.

Comment: Out of order doesn't worry me. The biggest concern is the fact that the result I observe is very different from the one in the documentation. Not only reordered - with duplicates. Example has none of those.

Comment: @alexakarpov bear in mind that in case of concurrency result can differ from machine to machine. The example that you have copied from clojuredocs is submitted by some random user and represents the output from his local machine. And as Stuart Halloway menitioned - the value that `commute` returns has nothing to do with the actual state of the ref after a transaction i.e. it's pretty random and you should not rely on it.

Comment: Perhaps it will be more clear if we are explicit about what the return values of your `dosync` are. `dosync` returns the result of the last expression evaluated inside it, in this case your `commute` call. And of course this `commute` may return the same value more than once: that's exactly what you asked for! Each transaction that completes commits a distinct, consistent value to your ref, but that still can't travel back in time and change what `commute` returned, and neither can it change what `dosync` returns.